# Object extension function TypeScript Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, extension-function

why is when I attempt the code

```
declare interface String {
  testsdfsdffds();
}

String.prototype.testsdfsdffds = () => {

};
```

it works, but substituting `Object` for `String` causes errors.  I thought you could extend Object without issues?

My goal really is to mimic the Kotlin `apply` and `let` extension functions - but I would like to understand the how/why you can/cant extend objects?

Comment: What errors do you get? Could you briefly explain what are you trying to achieve (for those unfamiliar with Kotlin)?

Comment: No, [it doesn't cause an error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20interface%20Object%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20testsdfsdffds()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.prototype.testsdfsdffds%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A(%7B%7D).testsdfsdffds()). Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. Any way, modified built-in prototypes have strong smell and should be avoided when possible, i.e. almost always.